# FileNotFoundError when trying to split audio

Tags: python, audio, pydub, filenotfounderror, audiosegment

I'm trying to split some audio files but I can't seem to find the solution for the error that occurs. I have imported `pydub` and `AudioSegment`.

```
audio_file = AudioSegment.from_mp3(abs_path_file)
```

This is the traceback:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Computer Science\Python\Programitas\split audio\split.py", line 16, in <module>
    audio_file = AudioSegment.from_mp3(abs_path_file)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

I updated ffmpeg but still nothing. Any help?

Comment: This appears to be a PATH issue. Have you added `ffmpeg` correctly to the PATH in Windows?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. It seems that it installed ffmpeg incorrectly the first time (I did it with pip). Now it's working. Thank you!